How can I remobe this app(apple music electron)
I can't remove this app whether by APP Center or by snap in terminal,Every time I want to remove it, it will pop a error, It's really odd and I can't believe that this happen to me because it's a ubuntu official snap, and I can't use this app either, every time I open it, it will pop a really emm.. odd window and I have to close it, So I can't use this app and I can't remove it as well



You should be able to remove the app by running snap remove apple-music-electron
The odd screen you see looks like a font problem, but I can't reproduce
it, maybe because of different language or system setup.
